# Configuring Metaware Toolchain Linker for Inserting Stabs Every 4KB Boundary in .text Section

Tags: c, memory-management, linker, embedded

I'm working with the Metaware toolchain and need assistance with manipulating the linker file to achieve a specific memory layout within the .text section. Specifically, I'm trying to insert 64-byte stabs at the end of every 4KB boundary within the .text section. The challenge is to ensure that code (functions) is appropriately placed around these stabs.

For a clearer illustration, here's what I'm aiming for:
Code: Address 0x0 - 0xFC0
Stab: Address 0xFC0 - 0x1000
Code: Address 0x1000 - 0x1FC0
Stab: Address 0x1FC0 - 0x2000
Code: Address 0x2000 - 0x2FC0
Stab: Address 0x2FC0 - 0x3000

I tried a lot of configuration but in all my attempts there where memory overlay or the stub was placed at the end of the .text section